# How to add filters to my site?

Tags: customization, filters

I've just started to use Wordpress for a few days to build a website. How can I add customizable filters to my site?

I'm using a free version, if this requires a payment? Which ones should I choose (I notice that there are some different upgrade plans as well as different WooCommerce pricing plans.

Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you might be using WordPress.com. If so, that's different than WordPress.org which this website helps with - try WordPress.com's own help section to better understand what options are available. If you are using WordPress.org, please help us understand what specifically you mean by "add customizable filters" as this could mean a few different things. :)

Comment: Yeah I'm using Wordpress.com. I heard that you need to know how to code to use Wordpress.org. By "add customizable filters", I mean filters that I can customize it, for example filter name or its position on the site. I've just paid for Woocommerce, they have filter plugins but I'm not sure how to modify it.

Comment: This site only covers WordPress.org. You definitely do not have to be a coder to use it, but of course the more you want to customize things, the more that helps. Best of luck to you!

Comment: Thank you for your answer.